# python manage.py runserver returning an attribute error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I created a python file in myapp and named it urls.py It looks like

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.home),
    path("predict/", views.predict),
    path("predict/result", views.result)
```

Also I edited The project's urls.py as instructed an it now looks like

```
  from django import views
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path("", views.home),
  path("predict/", views.predict),
  path("predict/result", views.result)
```

The views.py in myapp looks like

```
def result(request):
  data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MAX\diabetes.csv")
  X = data.drop("Outcome", axis=1)
  Y = data['Outcome']
  X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

  model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
  model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

  val1 = float(request.Get['n1'])
  val2 = float(request.Get['n2'])
  val3 = float(request.Get['n3'])
  val4 = float(request.Get['n4'])
  val5 = float(request.Get['n5'])
  val6 = float(request.Get['n6'])
  val7 = float(request.Get['n7'])
  val8 = float(request.Get['n8'])

  pared = model.predict([[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8,]])

result1 = ""
if pared == [1]:
   result1 = "positive"
elif pared == [0]:
   result1 = 'negative'
return render(request, "predict", {"result": result1})
```

The traceback is
AttributeError: module 'django.views' has no attribute 'home'

I expected the server to run successfully

Comment: You missed to post the error traceback. But it looks like a problem with case-sensitivity.

Comment: path("", views.home),

Comment: not sure I am getting you

Answer (score 1):

Hey just went through the code

1. The `view` you are refering is it inside folder django, if yes then your code will be creating issues as django is a reserved word and your package structure will be overwriting it.

   It should be named like `from your_app import views` and if the folder is named django rename it.
2. Again there is similar issue in views with you using another library name called `requests` which a library to help send requests. Also on side note a typo which I found was `Get()` it should be `GET()` all caps

Comment: The  view is inside myapp folder.....I applied the caps